# Comparison using modifiable signs (python)

Tags: python, comparison

In Python, is there a way of comparing values using a variable comparison sign? For example, I want to be able to change the sign to be `<` or `>`, and have the `if` statement still work.

The code below shows the idea, but it is not valid in Python:

```py
sign = <
if 1 sign 2:
    print("This works")
```

Comment: No I don't think this functionality is possible in python.

Answer (score 3):

Python's operators like `<` and `>` aren't values, so you can't assign them to variables. However, functions are values in Python, so you can assign them. The [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module has functions named `lt` and `gt` respectively:

```py
>>> from operator import lt, gt
>>> lt(1, 2)
True
>>> gt(1, 2)
False
>>> sign = lt
>>> sign(1, 2)
True
```

So you could write:

```py
from operator import lt, gt

sign = lt

if sign(1, 2):
    print('This works')
```